# The method setXmlStandalone(boolean) is undefined for the type Document

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-7

I have an eclipse project in which I am creating XML. The project worked fine till I decided to checkout my project into a new workspace. Suddenly, eclipse started complaining that

> The method setXmlStandalone(boolean) is undefined for the type
>   Document

My corresponding code is

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory= DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder=documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document documentObj=documentBuilder.newDocument();

documentObj.setXmlStandalone(true);
```

I have both JDK7 and JDK8 installed on my system. I have also enabled project specific settings in eclipse and set JDK 7 for installed JREs and Java Build Path for my project.

I also looked into Document.class file, it actually doesn't seem to have setXmlStandalone function. But I have verified on other systems that Document.class file does have this specific function(checked in JDK 6 and 7).

How should I solve this problem ?
Edit:

I removed all JDK versions from my PC (except for JDK6 which is needed for another project). Installed JDK 7 and tried a fresh checkout in Eclipse Luna. But still have the same problem.

Comment: are you sure nothing is messed up with imports? can you add fully-qualified name of Document class (with package name)?
And where did you find Document.class, in your project or in jdk?

Comment: [`Document.setXmlStandalone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#setXmlStandalone-boolean-) is clearly listed as part of the official public API. Are you sure that your Eclipse version is Java 8 compatible?

Comment: @Holger I am using Eclipse Luna and trying to use JDK 7.

Comment: @sakfa, I found it in JDK (by Ctrl+Click on Document in my Java file in Eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. I removed every other version of JDK from my system and cleaned the disk, environment paths, registries etc. This still didn't solve the problems.

I noticed that while checking out the project, the JRE version was being unbound. So every time I was removing it and adding the JDK version from my system. This was doing all well, except for the fact that the JRE was added at the bottom of the hierarchy in "Order and Export". Moving it up the hierarchy (above Tomcat, WebApp and EAR libraries), fixed the problem.

Comment: If the order is relevant, it implies that there is another version of the `org.w3c.dom.Document` class in the path which is not compatible. This is dangerous as it means that there could be implementations of this interface not implementing the absent methods at the same location. I strongly recommend further investigations regarding where the incompatible version of the interface came from and which implications that might have. Maybe, it’s not relevant and you can even remove entries from your class path. But if it is, you better fix it now…